# Error: model item passed into the dictionary is of type '....List', but this dictionary requires a model of type '...IEnumerable`

Tags: model-view-controller

I encountered this error while trying to render an asp.net MVC 3.0 application.
I am working with DAB Architecture (3 projects) **CAFM.Web, CAFM.Business**, and **CAFM.Data** projects.

**CAFM.Data includes**

CAFMEntities : Entity FrameWork
ITabMaster : Interface
namespace CAFM.Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface ITabMaster
    {
        TabMaster GetTabMasterById(Int64 id);
        IEnumerable FindTabMasterByName(string name);
        void AddTabMaster(TabMaster tabmaster);
        IEnumerable GetAllTabMaster();
    }
}

**CAFM.Business includes**
reference of CAFM.Data
namespace CAFM.Business.Repositories
{
    public class TabMasterRepository : ITabMaster
    {
        public int colID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

```
    private CAFMEntities _context;

    public TabMasterRepository()
    {
        //IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new CAFMEntities();
        _context = new CAFMEntities();
    }

    public TabMasterRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (unitOfWork == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");

        _context = unitOfWork as CAFMEntities;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TabMaster> GetAllTabMaster()
    {
        //(extension)List<Movie> IEnumerable<Movie>.ToList<Movie>()
        //List<TabMaster> tabmasters = _context.TabMasters.ToList();
        return _context.TabMasters.ToList() ;// .AsEnumerable<TabMaster>();//.ToList();
        //return tabmasters;
    }

    public TabMaster GetTabMasterById(Int64 id)
    {
        return _context.TabMasters.Where(c => c.colID == id).Single();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TabMaster> FindTabMasterByName(string name)
    {
        return _context.TabMasters.Where(c => c.LastName.StartsWith(name)).AsEnumerable<TabMaster>(); //.ToList();
    }

    public void AddTabMaster(TabMaster tabmaster)
    {
        _context.TabMasters.AddObject(tabmaster);
    }
}
```

}

**CAFM.Web includes**
reference of CAFM.Data
namespace CAFM.Web.Controllers
{
    public class TabMasterController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /TabMaster/

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {

        //Error comes in following line. (_context.TabMasters.ToList() is successfully return all the values but error is The model item passed into the dictionary is ... during rendering HTML 
        TabMasterRepository tr = new TabMasterRepository();
        return View(tr.GetAllTabMaster());
    }

}
```

}

**Index.cshtml contains**

@model IEnumerable
@{
    Layout = null;
}



    TabMaster

### List of Movies

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

ID
            
            
                First Name
            
            
                Last Name
            
        
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            
                
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.colID)
                
                
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                
                
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                
            
        }

**Error Description:**
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CAFM.Data.TabMaster]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CAFM.Business.Repositories.TabMasterRepository]'.

Please provide your valuable suggestion to resolve above error.

Your answer would be appreciated!
Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why do you want your repository in a view. Did you try to change model to

```
@model List<CAFM.Data.TabMaster>
```

In MVC you should pass data between controller and view thru ViewModels

Comment: you are right. could you please provide me sample application with MVC 3.0 using (.Web, .Business and .Data) Architecture?  Please help me if you can!

Comment: I am sorry but if there is nothing what you are looking for on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site i can't help you because this is only thing which I know that is using Entity Framework. Try to google more and look here on stackoverflow. You should practice on nerddinner.com [here](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/releases/view/45647) is the source for MVC 2.0 and [walkthru](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part1.htm) in MVC 1 but They are still relevant. If you want to walkthru in MVC 2 you have to buy a [book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html)